# View list of messages in mail/mailx

Tags: email, mailx

Using `mail` (`mailx`), how does one refresh the list of messages, as it appears immediately upon starting the program? After I run a command to view a particular message, I cannot reload the list (except by exitting and re-running the program).

E.g.

```
Heirloom mailx version 12.5 6/20/10.  Type ? for help.
"/var/mail/me": 3 messages
 O  1 Mail System Intern Tue Nov 11 03:26   13/601   DON'T DELETE THIS MESSAGE -- FOLDER INTERNAL DATA
>F  2 My Name   Sat May  2 21:47 2632/79829 Fwd: Ticketless Travel Passenger Itinerary
 O  3 foo@example.com Sun May 10 15:39  958/20019 Re: Fwd: Ticketless Travel Passenger Itinerary
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can refresh the message list by typing the command `headers` (or `h` for abbreviation).